# htaccess rewriteCond using custom http header

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

There are a thousand threads on this but I must be missing something as I can't get it to work.

My nginx load balancer decrypts SSL traffic and proxies it (via Varnish) through to the content servers. It adds a custom header to the proxied request:

```
proxy_set_header "IS-HTTPS" "1";
```

I can SEE this HTTP header from the content servers:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER["HTTP_IS_HTTPS"]);
?>
```

This will output **string(1) "1"** on a HTTPS connection, and **NULL** on a HTTP.

So, my .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:IS_HTTPS} !="1"

RewriteRule ^(securebit.*)$ https:// %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work. Just gets into a redirect loop.

(NB: the space in "// %" isn't there. StackOverflow validation is falling over on it.)

Neither do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:IS_HTTPS} !=1
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:IS_HTTPS} !1
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_IS_HTTPS} !="1"
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_IS_HTTPS} !=1
```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_IS_HTTPS} !1
```

What simple, obvious and frustrating mistake am I making?

Comment: first, this `!=` is not valid in `RewriteCond`, use negative pattern instead. Also `%{HTTP:header}` means real HTTP-header like Host `%{HTTP:Host}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To clarify: Firstly, I'm referring to the docs at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond which do seem to indicate that `!=` is a valid conditional operator. Secondly, [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) does set a real HTTP header.

Comment: I rely on official docs. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Ah. Official docs good. So, "Does not equal 1" would therefore be written as `RewriteCond %{HTTP:TCW_HTTPS} !^1$` ? Because that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: check all variables are properly defined by passing them as script parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when nginx that was listening on both http and https ports was forwarding the traffic to a local apache instance.

In the nginx configuration i added:

```
proxy_set_header X-Request-Protocol $scheme; #http or https
```

In the .htaccess file i added this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Request-Protocol} ^http$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't redirect with a querystring

Comment: You could append QSA after L at the last line.

Comment: @Jordan Yes it does. (The `QSA` flag is not required here, as the original query string is passed through by default.)

Answer (score 2):

you set  "IS-HTTPS" and you check for "IS_HTTPS" ?